# Date is showing null in MongoDb

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add Date field in MongoDb and sending date from android and trying to save in MongoDb.I am using:

```
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    String time = formatter.format(date);
```

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
 private void saveRetailer(){

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    String time = formatter.format(date);

     OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("time",time)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().post(formBody).url(URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        String resp = response.body().string();
                        prog1.dismiss();

                        if(resp.equals("Data added")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),resp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    prog1.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    });
 }
```

**Addretailer.js**

```
router.post('/saveRetailer',(req,res) => {

const data = {
         time:req.body.time 
};

  MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {

                          if(err){
                              console.log("Error",err);
                          }
                          else{

                            const coll = client.db("mydb").collection("mycollection");
                            coll.insertOne(data,(err,resp) => {

                                      if(err){
                                          console.log("Error",err);
                                      }
                                      else{
                                        res.send("Data added");
                                      }
                            });
                     }
       });

  });
```

It is saving `time:null` in MongoDb. Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Is question related to android or mongo db ?

Comment: I am not sure where actually problem is becoz in android it is logging correct date and time.

Comment: If it's logging correctly then it should be related to mongo db

Comment: can you please print what you get in req object in Addretailer.js file?